# В сравнении с... Присоединительный член предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

***Палисадов, в сравнении с ним, (—) ничтожество.***

Что собой представляет оборот *в сравнении с ним*? Предполагаю, что это присоединительный член предложения.

Нужно ли тире перед *ничтожество*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Палисадов, в сравнении с ним, ― ничтожество.**

1. Такой вариант оформления есть в "Справочнике по пунктуации", при этом обособление оборота указано как **факультативное**. Оборот чаще обособляется  **в середине предложения.**

[**В СРАВНЕНИИ / ПО СРАВНЕНИЮ С (кем, чем),** *предлог*](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_793&layout=item)

> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогами «в сравнении с», «по сравнению с», могут обособляться.
>
> *И правда, риск самовольного побега был ничтожен **в сравнении с** наслаждениями, ожидавшими Александрова.* А. Куприн, Юнкера.
> *Мои испытания, **в сравнении с** твоими, ― киндершпиль, детская игра…* А. Куприн, Колесо времени.

2. **О грамматике предложения**

Это простое осложненное предложение с обособленным обстоятельством. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым (Палисадов ― ничтожество). Постановка тире и запятой независимая.

***По сравнению с ним*** ―  **обстоятельственный оборот** с производным предлогом, присоединения здесь нет.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Александр, в этом ответе, как мне кажется,  есть грамматическая неточность. Вы ее видите?

Comment: Пока нет (сейчас чуть-чуть некада). А вот уведомление о сообщении мне не пришло. Наверно, из-за пробела между именем и фамилией.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  А, это да. Я, правда. иногда стараюсь писать правильно... Ну на досуге подумайте. Мне эта неточность  просто бросилась в глаза, но никто и ничего не видит.  Вот что за народ!

Comment: Стопятьсот раз прочитал... Что я за народ – тоже не вижу! Не запятую же ставить перед "как факультативное". Может, это предложение надо перестроить: *"Это простое осложненное предложение с обособленным обстоятельством"*.  *Это простое, осложненное обособленным обстоятельством предложение*. Или лучше так: *Это простое предложение, осложненное обособленным обстоятельством.*

Comment: Читать, пожалуй, хватит.  Это – шутка! Там все правильно. Вот что за народ - шуток не понимают.   Извините меня пожалуйста, это я ошиблась.  Но вот почему – уж точно не догадаетесь!..

Comment: Совсем меня запутали... Где шутка, где ошибка – конечно не догадаюсь. Подéлитесь или уже проехали?

Comment: Проехали!  Но я нечаянно, извините.  Я не так прочитала текст, как нужно. Так его прочитает только один человек из миллиона, так что стоит задуматься.

Comment: Заинтриговали окончательно :)) Теперь буду периодически читать, чтобы стать этим одним :))